# URL missing trailing slash returns 404 instead of index.jsp

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans-8

I'm trying to run locally a Java webApp developed with NetBeans 8, TomCat 8 using Spring MVC. The dispatcherServlet is mapped on /.
The application runs at the URL localhost:8080/webApp on other PCs.

Only on my PC the application needs a trailing slash, while localhost:8080/webApp returns *404 - The requested resource is not available.*

Why this happens only to my PC? What could I do?

Thank you very much

Comment: As far as I understood from your question, the server is running on a different machine and in order to access that web app from a different machine you might have to access it from the IP address of that machine instead of `localhost:8080/webApp`. Eg: `10.0.0.1:8080/webApp` here 10.0.0.1 is the IP address of the machine running the web app.

Comment: I'm trying to run the application locally. I modified the message so this is clearer now. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: This is still not clear. How is "your PC" different than ... something else that you haven't defined?

Comment: There are several differences, starting from the NetBeans version and the TomCat version (although I also tried their TomCat version). I asked the question because I believed it would be some known configuration problem or NetBeans bug.

Comment: Anyway I'm not saying "it doesn't work, i don't know why". I'm giving a specific symptom: the app works only if I add a / to the URL.